# SQL: Concatenar los ID de registros agrupados

Tags: sql

¿Como puedo concatenar los `ID` de cada registro agrupado con `Group By`?.

Originalmente tengo esta tabla

| ID | Producto | Calidad | Tamaño | Peso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | A | 5.4 |
| 2 | A | A | A | 3.6 |
| 3 | A | B | A | 1.2 |
| 4 | A | B | A | 2.0 |
| 5 | A | C | A | 5.0 |

Si agrupo por Producto, Calidad y tamaño quiero obtener este resultado

| Producto | Calidad | Tamaño | SumaPeso | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | 9.0 | 1,2 |
| A | B | A | 3.2 | 3,4 |
| A | C | A | 5.0 | 5 |

La consulta quedaría algo así

```
Select Producto,Calidad,Tamaño,sum(peso), ¿concatenar id? 
From Productos 
Group By Producto,Calidad,Tamaño
```

No he podido dar con la funcion que me concatene los id, desde ya agradesco sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos estas usando?

Comment: En MySQL tienes `GROUP_CONCAT(ID)` para esa finalidad